# How to get onclick to display contents of php file

Tags: javascript, php, onclick

I am having a problem getting an onclick function to work.
Clicking on "units" in the HTML file, "unit_test" disappears and the contents of unit_display.php shows up instead.  This is what I want to happen.

If I click on "Phoenix", however, "prop_test" remains and the results of prop_display.php do not appear.

I can browse to prop_display.php?city=Phoenix and it will pull up the list of properties from that table, so this rules out prop_display.php code as the culprit.

Here is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script>

function showProp(str) {
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("propDisplay").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","prop_display.php?city="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
}

function showUnit(str) {
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("unitDisplay").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","unit_display.php?prop_id="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div onclick="showProp(Phoenix)"><a href="#">Properties</a></div>
<div onclick="showUnit(8)"><a href="#">units</a></div>
<br>
<div id="propDisplay">prop_test</div>
<div id="unitDisplay">unit_test</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is prop_display.php:

```
<?php
include('vars.php');
$city = strval($_GET['city']);
print $city;
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
if ($prop_query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM property WHERE city='$city' ORDER BY street asc")){}
while ($prop_array = mysqli_fetch_array($prop_query, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
    $prop_id=$prop_array['prop_id'];
    print " <li><div onclick=\"showUnit($prop_id)\"><a href=\"#\">" . $prop_array['name'] . "<br>
    " . $prop_array['street'] . "</a></div>
";
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

And here is unit_display.php:

```
<?php
include('vars.php');
$prop_id = intval($_GET['prop_id']);
print $prop_id;
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
if ($unit_query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM units WHERE prop_id='$prop_id' ORDER BY unit asc")){}
while ($unit_array = mysqli_fetch_array($unit_query, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
    print " <li><a href=\"#\" target=\"_blank\">" . $unit_array['unit'] . "</a></li>
";
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: This is open to an serious SQL injection. Best for you to use a prepared statement if you don't want your database to go *\*Poof!\**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to have them click with `Phoenix` being an object when it should be a string.

Replace this:

```
<div onclick="showProp(Phoenix)"><a href="#">Properties</a></div>
```

with this:

```
<div onclick="showProp('Phoenix')"><a href="#">Properties</a></div>
```